# Member hiding, what is its practical purpose

Tags: c#, oop, new-operator, liskov-substitution-principle

What is the actual practical use of the ['new' modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)?

```
public class Base
{
    public void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

public class Derived:Base
{
    public new void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }
}
```

It wouldn't it better if this just fails to compile? This code:

```
        Derived d = new Derived();
        d.Say();
        ((Base)d).Say();
```

Returns

```
 Derived
 Base
```

Doesn't this break the Liskov substitution principle?

Cheers.

Comment: Laws can be broken or bent when they meet the real world - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding LSP**

That doesn't break the LSP.
The LSP states that if `Derived` is a subtype of `Base`, then any code depending on `Base` (e.g, a method with a `Base` parameter, like `void DoSomething(Base b)`) can be replaced with an instance of `Derived`, without any surprising effects.

And as you pointed out, if you assign an instance of `Derived` to a `Base` variable, the `Base` implementation will be called.

That's the expected behaviour, since `Say` is not virtual. This means that code written against a `Base` variable, expects the `Base` implementation to be called.

**Practical purpose**

You can think of `new` methods as a way to circumvent a non-overridable method - with a caveat! You'll have to program against that specific type - not its interface.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not a good practice to do it, I can see it being useful when you inherit from a third party assembly (i.e. Code you don't have control over ) and you want to have a different behavior for a method.

Comment: But you're *not* overriding one of the methods when you do this.  That's kinda the point.

Comment: I didn't mean override keyword but having a different behavior. I will update the answer...

Comment: I'm not talking about override as in the keyword, but as in the concept.  You answer has the same problem as you're refferring to the same concept.  If the method is virtual and you override it then you really are effectively changing the implementation of the method.  When hiding you are, from a conceptual standpoint, just creating an entirely new method (hence the use of the `new` keyword) and explicitly *not* changing the existing method.  It is still there, completely unchanged.

Comment: Agreed... I have changed it to say "if you want to have a different behavior"

Answer (score 1):

A method in derived class is considered "related" to a method in its base class if it has the same name and parameter list. Compiler designers have two ways of dealing with such related methods:

1. **Rely upon a convention** - for example, they could declare such methods an override; Java does that.
2. **Request explicit direction from programmers** - C# designers took that route: they ask programmers to designate related methods with `virtual`/`override`, and unrelated methods with `new`.

The first way of handling elated methods leaves programmers no choice: if they want an unrelated methods, they *must* give it a different name. The second way leaves the choice with the programmer, at the expense of being more verbose.

Essentially, the `new` keyword lets you communicate to the compiler that the method that you've added is unrelated to a method in the base class that has the same name and parameters.

> Doesn't this break the Liskov substitution principle?

Arguably, it does not: the fact that the derived class has introduced a method with the same name and parameters, which the programmer explicitly designated as unrelated to the method in the base, does not change anything in the behavior of the derived class in situations when it is used as a stand-in for its base class.

Answer (score 1):

It simply allows the user to redefine the method in the base class. Naturally, had the developer foreseen this happenstance, you'd hope they'd have coded it as virtual (for a default implementation) or abstract (where any implementation needs to be specified).

The LSP simply put just requires that a base class and sub class can be used interchangeably so this doesn't violate the principle as far as I can see.

A foible of C# is that only one class can be inherited so a case such as this should be relatively rare for complex systems where the multiple implementation of interfaces would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

This can be useful when `Base` and clients of `Derived` are out of your control. Suppose you started with this.

```
public class Base
{
  // there is no Say method in Base!
}

public class Derived:Base
{
    public /*new*/ void Say() // we don't need new here
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }
}
```

Then someday those who are in charge of `Base` added cool `Say` method there. You could have renamed `Derived.Say`, but it's already used elsewhere by code you cannot change. So you use `new` to avoid breaking changes in `Derived`.

```
public class Base
{
    public void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

public class Derived:Base
{
    public new void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
    }
}

public class SomeClient
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var d = new Derived();
        d.Say();
    }
}
```